# Using GCP secrets as part of cloud build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to pass in confidential info into a bash script that is part of our cloud build process
I've followed the [CloudBuild docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets) to try set it all up.
After many many different tires copied the docker example as a test even that is not working.
Here is what I have at the moment

```
*gcloud secrets list*
NAME     CREATED              REPLICATION_POLICY  LOCATIONS
SECRET1  2021-08-18T04:37:47  automatic           -
SECRET2  2021-08-18T04:38:11  automatic           -

*gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="SECRET1"*
Secret2Value
*gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="SECRET2"*
Secret2Value

**cloudbuild.yaml**
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker login --username=$$USERNAME --password=$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET1/versions/1
    env: 'PASSWORD'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET2/versions/latest
    env: 'USERNAME'
```

[image: CloudBuild execution]

My understanding was that it would substituite the value of SECRET1 and SECRET2 into the USERNAME and PASSWORD envs but I'm getting $USERNAME and $PASSWORD
**Arguments**
bash -c docker login --username=$USERNAME --password=$PASSWORD

Feels like I've missed something simple yet fundamental

== Update ==
Here is the full build log

```
FETCHSOURCE
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default     branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use     in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this     command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/amiti-plex-can-    dev/r/bitbucket_noldortech_amiti-payments
 * branch            a72363459d9ff5bed31411e960cc3e021febc322 ->     FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at a723634 Secrets test 1
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/":     unauthorized: incorrect username or password
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited     with non-zero status: 1
```

== Update 2==
After testing the echo commands below, I switched over to using a script, which is what I actually need.

```
**Yaml File:**
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'echo Username=$$USERNAME && echo Password=$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['cloudbuilds/script.sh', '$$USERNAME', '$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET1/versions/1
    env: 'PASSWORD'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET2/versions/latest
    env: 'USERNAME'
    
**Script:**
#/bin/bash
secretVar1="$1"
secretVar2="$2"
printf "\n\nVARIABLES\nSecret1: $secretVar1\nSecret2: $secretVar2\n\n"

**Build Log:**
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0: Username=Secret2Value
Step #0: Password=Secret1Value
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #1: 
Step #1: 
Step #1: VARIABLES
Step #1: Secret1: $USERNAME
Step #1: Secret2: $PASSWORD
Step #1: 
Finished Step #1
PUSH
DONE
```

Comment: Do you have more details on the job failure in the logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I added the build log

Comment: Incorrect username and password. Are you sure of the values?

Comment: The username/password are not valid but thats because its not even pulling them from the secrets. Its passing $USERNAME and $PASSWORD to the login command instead of the values of the secrets

Comment: Can you check the value that you get from Cloud Build by changing the arg value by this one: `args: ['-c', 'echo $$USERNAME && echo $$PASSWORD']`

Comment: That seems to work
   `BUILD
    Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    Username=Secret2Value
    Password=Secret1Value
    PUSH
    DONE`

Comment: Therefore the credential are wrong, it's not a secret manager or cloud build issue!

Comment: This is a test script, when I tried with my actually script none of the values were assigned.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your CloudBuild implementation. It's pretty much the same as it's mentioned in the official documentation. As guillaume mentioned, do the same troubleshoot by printing the values in your real script and also, just as an additional debug step you could manually pass the password/username in a cloudbuild step (without using secret) to see whether your account will successfully log in or not.

Comment: The docker login was just a test and I expected it to fail as the credentials were made up. As you can see by Update 2, when I pass these to a simple bash script I do not get the values of the secret, thats the real issue I'm having. The docker file was simply step 1 in trying to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the correct yaml syntax to execute my script as I need

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', ". ./cloudbuilds/script.sh $$SOMEVAR1 $$SOMEVAR2"]
  secretEnv: ['SOMEVAR1', 'SOMEVAR2']
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET1/versions/1
    env: 'SOMEVAR2'
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/SECRET2/versions/latest
    env: 'SOMEVAR1'

BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
VARIABLES
Secret1: Secret2Value
Secret2: Secret1Value
PUSH
DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

USERNAME & PASSWORD are environment variables, for them to be expanded on the command line, you need to run the command via the shell. (Note that doing so is considered bad practice from a security perspective.)

This is why only the first step works in your second update.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean run it via the shell?

Comment: bash -c "command with argument here" will evaluate "command with argument here" and expand any environment variable.